# How to view register values in TASM?

Tags: assembly

I'm learning assembly through turbo assembler.
Whenever i assemble a program , it assembles and executes perfectly but without any data on screen.For eg.(the changes that took place inside the registers etc).
So is there any way i can check the output.

I don't want to use a debugger.

I jusy want to know whether there is any command or interrupt or anything that can help me with output.

P.s : I can output string or chars but not values or register content

Comment: If you are planning to program in assembler, learn to use a debugger. That is the most typical way to verify execution of your code when there is no screen output and to debug code that doesn't run properly.

Comment: An assembler's job is assembling instructions. How can it debug a program?

Comment: So **you want exactly what a debugger gives you**, but you don't want to use one.  Good luck with that.  Using a debugger is *much* easier in asm than adding debug-prints.  Printing anything changes the state of at least some registers, so adding it will have an effect on the code you're debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TASM is just assembler, it has no idea what are the values of registers during runtime of your code. So the answer to your question is "you can't.".

During runtime either you have some external way to check the values (**debugger obviously**, or in case you are using some virtual machine, it may provide some debugging interface to check state of it).

Or you output it internally, on screen, or logging to file, or trough network/serial line, or just beeping/blinking something. (this is usually quite inferior way of debugging when compared to debugger, but sometimes for various reasons can be preferred)

*"I can output string or chars but not values or register content"*
- this doesn't make any sense. If you can output chars, you can output any text, also values. Just convert them into text.

For example 456 can be displayed as string `'4', '5', '6'`.
Or `'1' 'C' '8'` in hexadecimal formatting (which is much simpler to do in assembler, as the CPU has the value base_2 encoded already, so converting it to base_16 needs just to pick groups of 4 base_2 digits to form base_16 digit ... ha! How to say in many words that exactly 4 bits form 0..F hexa digit :D ).

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking a 'C' run-time library call `printf` or `itoa`, or a reasonable facsimile written by hand, on the register value(s) you are interested in.

Comment: No library...just plain assembly.

Answer (score 1):

**Why not using a debugger? heres one that can help you:**

run it using turbo debugger, after u got your exe file just run using DosBox and Turbo Debugger installed in the same directory as your exe file the next command:

```
td YourFileName
```

Then choose from the upper menu from the opened view the view tab and cpu.
U can run the program using f7(1 step) or f9(full run) and see the registers value updating while you run it.

Comment: I sort of wonder where all those TASM people nowadays buy that SW, I thought it's not possible to get a legal copy of TASM/TD today.

Comment: @Ped7g Studying it at school :D
Israel really invest in cyber/hitech education

Comment: In my utterly subjective opinion, there's **free** and well supported NASM, with almost the same syntax, just a bit simpler (IMO better). Although some "ND" is sort of missing to make the replacement complete and straightforward. Yeah, I'm pushing it. :)

Comment: @Ped7g Always wanted to learn that, but they sticked with the 8086 since its "easier" to understand